# json errors when appending data with Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, sqlite, append

Good day.

I have a small password generator program and I want to save the created passwords into a json file (append each time) so I can add them to an SQLITE3 database.

Just trying to do the append functionality I receive several errors that I don't understand.
Here are the errors I receive and below that is the code itself.

I'm quite new to Python so additional details are welcomed.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\whitmech\OneDrive - Six Continents Hotels, Inc\04 - Python\02_Mosh_Python_Course\Py_Projects\PWGenerator.py", line 32, in 
> data = json.load(file)
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 293, in load
> return loads(fp.read(),
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json_*init*_.py", line 346, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
> File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
> raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
> json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

```
import random
import string
import sqlite3
import json
from pathlib import Path

print('hello, Welcome to Password generator!')

# input the length of password
length = int(input('\nEnter the length of password: '))

# define data
lower = string.ascii_lowercase
upper = string.ascii_uppercase
num = string.digits
symbols = string.punctuation
# string.ascii_letters

# combine the data
all = lower + upper + num + symbols

# use random
temp = random.sample(all, length)

# create the password
password = "".join(temp)

filename = 'saved.json'
entry = {password}

with open(filename, "r+") as file:
    data = json.load(file)
    data.append(entry)
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file)

# print the password
print(password)
```

Update: I've changed the JSON code as directed and it works but when trying to do the SQLite3 code I'm knowing receiving a typeerror

Code:

```
with open(filename, "r+") as file:
    try:
        data = json.load(file)
        data.append(entry)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        data = entry
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file)

# print the password
print(password)

store = input('Would you like to store the password? ')

if store == "Yes":
    pwStored = json.loads(Path("saved.json").read_text())
    with sqlite3.connect("db.pws") as conn:
        command = "INSERT INTO Passwords VALUES (?)"
        for i in pwStored:
            conn.execute(command, tuple(i.values)) # Error with this code
        conn.commit()
else:
    exit()
```

Error:

> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Answer (score 0):

The error is because

- Your json file is empty, you need to update the following block

```py
entry = [password]

with open(filename, "r+") as file:
    try:
        data = json.load(file)
        data.extend(entry)
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError as e:
        data = entry
    file.seek(0)
    json.dump(data, file)
```

- Also you are adding password in a set ie., `entry`, and it will again throw you an error `TypeError: Object of type set is not JSON serializable`
  So you need to convert that to either a `list` or `dict`

> Note: Here I have used `entry` as a list

Comment: Thanks - this worked, I updated the OP as I'm having a Sqlite error I wonder if you can assist with that?

Comment: Since you stored the passwords in a list, so when you load the json, you will get a list of passwords. and when you iterate, you will get a string in each step. Also, `conn.execute` requires command and tuple, so you need to convert that string into tuple like this `conn.execute(command, tuple((i,)))`

I hope this works for you?

Comment: This seems to have fixed one error but created another but it's related to sqlite
"sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type."